# Automate package version update with Continuous Integration in Bamboo

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, bamboo

I have a query on how others accomplish this and what, if any, the best practices are.  I have an application that comprises three packages and they are setup in Bamboo for CI/CD.

The issue I am experiencing is that of how to automate the update of the package version on each build, e.g. `npm version patch` to bump the package version.

What I would like to know is how other accomplish these, I have thought about manually running `npm version patch` but that is not ideal and would be prone to errors (eg. forgetting to run this).  I had also thought of adding a step in Bamboo to run `npm version patch` during the build but Bamboo clones the repository with out remotes and there unable to commit the change, otherwise every build would be the same version and still no better off.

An example is that we have a package which is an Electron application and when the build runs generates an MSI and .yml file for the auto updater, without incrementing the version the MSI will always be the same version and therefore the auto update would not work.

So what are the strategies for automating the version of an npm package for each build? What do others do in similar situations?